# Перестаёт обновляться ng-repeat при большом числе элементов

Tags: javascript, angularjs

При использовании лимита количества видимых элементов (limitTo) всё нормально.

Но при попытке обойтись без него (отображение в прокручиваемом блоке) после штук 30-40 элементов начинаются проблемы: список перестаёт обновляться, а элементы перестают удаляться при клике. Если покликать рандомно на разные элементы, может на пару обновлений «отвиснуть» и потом опять встаёт намертво.

С чем это может быть связано? Какой-то баг js, вызываемый при слишком большом содержимом блока со скроллом?

```
<div class="ui-list-view-bordered" ui-list-view="edit in edits|limitTo:4">
    <div ng-click="select(edit); remove(edit);">{{edit.wiki}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не могли бы вы предоставить песочницу где воспроизводится данная проблема? Потому что даже не известно что за директива ui-list-view

Comment: @UserTest013 Здесь я использую популярный элемент [ui-listView](https://github.com/StevenLambion/ui-listView). Но, кажется, что-то с ним не то. Упрощённый пример с проблемой [тут](https://tools.wmflabs.org/iluvatarbot/test/).

Comment: Я бы не сказал что этот ui-listView популярный :) Старый и давно не обновляется.

Мне кажется проблема во вложенном ng-repeat="cell in listView.cells".  Angular loop просто не справляется с настолько большим количеством элементов, которые ему надо постоянно перерисовать.

Попробуйте добавить track-by, возможно порог в 30-40 элементов увеличится до 200-300
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39640160/what-is-track-by-in-angularjs-and-how-does-it-work
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: @UserTest013 Методом тыка обнаружил, что это вовсе не от числа элементов зависит. А от размера блока по вертикали. Как только появляется скролл, обновление отрисовки останавливается. Если скролл чуть сдвинуть, то все задержанные элементы отрисовываются, и опять засыпает. Дело в скролле. Почему-то не происходит его обновление.